# Unable to deploy React-App and Express API on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, express, vercel

Good morning,

I am developing a react application: a website.
I installed a backend server on my project: express (npm install express).

I managed to setup my backend and get the api to work locally on my machine except when I pushed it to vercel it was impossible to get the backend api to work!!

here is my server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv'); // Import the dotenv module

// Load environment variables from the .env file
dotenv.config();

// Middleware to allow requests from any origin (replace * with your frontend domain in production)
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

// Test endpoint to check if the backend is working correctly
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Backend is working!' });
});

// Endpoint to handle an action that requires using authentication keys
app.get('/api/keys', (req, res) => {
    // You can now access environment variables using process.env
    const SERVICE_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID;
    const TEMPLATE_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID;
    const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY;
    const FREE_USER = process.env.REACT_APP_FREE_USER;
    const FREE_PASS = process.env.REACT_APP_FREE_PASS;

    // For example purposes, let's simply return the authentication keys in JSON format
    res.json({ SERVICE_ID, TEMPLATE_ID, PUBLIC_KEY, FREE_USER, FREE_PASS });
});

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; // You can set the port from environment variables
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The backend server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and this is how I use the api in my page:

```
// Comment: Function to test the API call and retrieve keys from the backend
const TEST = async () => {
    // API call to fetch the keys
    const response = await axios.get('/api/keys');
    // Data received from the backend
    const data = response.data;
    // Log the keys to the console
    console.log(
        data.SERVICE_ID + " // " +
        data.TEMPLATE_ID + " // " +
        data.PUBLIC_KEY + " // " +
        data.FREE_USER + " // " +
        data.FREE_PASS + " // "
    )
}
```

here is a picture of my files : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsOry.png)

vercel.json code :

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/server/server.js" }
  ]
}
```

I have no error in vercel.
here is the build & developement settings of vercel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrnE9.png)

when I go to the api of my site I see nothing (https://mywebsite/api/test)

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR HELP !!